# update variable value in another component every time the button is clicked

Tags: react-draft-wysiwyg

I am making a text editor using react-draft-wysiwyg for it in reactJS. I want to set the updated value of variable **value** in mobile.js file as soon as the button from editor.js file is clicked. Rigth now I am just updating it in editor.js file on click. But in the code below the value is not updated on every click. How can I update the value of  `value` in mobile.js file whenever the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Mobile` component you need to edit from `{this.value}` to `{value}` and from `export const Mobile = () => {` to `export const Mobile = ({ value }) => {`.

The problem is that you are not reading the `value` prop from `Mobile`'s parent and you are trying to read `this.value` which is `undefined` inside a functional component.